# PHP: Regex for find any in {}

Tags: php, regex

I use strings with this characters: { and }
Example:

> Logged in with IP-Adress {ipAdress}

Or other example:

> Your username was {userName}

Now i need a regex to find any strings, i tried this:

```
preg_match_all('/^{(.+)}/', $string, $matches)
```

But this don't find that...
Who can help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/\{(.+?)\}/', $string, $matches)
```

`{`s are special in regular expressions. You need to escape them.

Additionally, `^` anchors to the start of the line.  Your pattern isn't at the start of a line.

Finally, per your comment below, you have more than one such demarcated string per line, so you want to use the non-greedy version of the search `.+?`.

Comment: Oh, i see at this time, that the result is wrong, look here:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(32) "{userName} mit der IP {ipAdress}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(30) "userName} mit der IP {ipAdress"
  }
}

This strings should be the result:
"{userName}" and "{ipAdress}"

Comment: If you have several on a line then you'll want to use a non-greedy qualifier on your `.+`, in php the non-greedy qualifier is ? so you'd use `.+?`

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all('/\{([^}]+)\}/', $string, $matches);`

Use the `.` sparingly. In this case `{[^}]+}` is more efficient.